# Nginx returning 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: debian, php, webserver, nginx

I'm trying to set up an Nginx webserver generally following [this guide](http://insready.com/en/blog/building-nginx-microcaching-mariadbmysql-php-fpm-debian-6-apc-memcache-drupal-7-server) but using [perusio's configuration](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx). When I try to access the site, I get a 502 Bad Gateway page.

Searching on the error I've seen a few people report that [setting the fastcgi buffer size](http://developernote.com/2012/09/how-i-fixed-nginx-502-bad-gateway-error/) has fixed their problem. However, this did not work for me. Though the messages in my error log are different than those stated:

```
2013/06/11 10:21:24 [info] 32684#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:181
2013/06/11 10:21:24 [alert] 32692#0: epoll_ctl(1, 0) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2013/06/11 10:21:24 [alert] 32692#0: failed to register channel handler while initializing push module worker (1: Operation not permitted)
2013/06/11 10:21:24 [alert] 32691#0: epoll_ctl(1, 0) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2013/06/11 10:21:24 [alert] 32691#0: failed to register channel handler while initializing push module worker (1: Operation not permitted)
2013/06/11 10:21:25 [alert] 32686#0: cache manager process 32691 exited with fatal code 2 and cannot be respawned
```

Searching on this error, it seems that `nginx` is not communicating with `php5-fpm`. I've verified that `php5-fpm` is running:

```
$ ps auxw | grep php
root       853  0.0  0.8 290416  4504 ?        Ss   10:21   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data   854  0.0  0.6 290416  3488 ?        S    10:21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www      
www-data   855  0.0  0.6 290416  3488 ?        S    10:21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www      
kyle       973  0.0  0.2   3824  1072 pts/0    S+   10:42   0:00 grep php
```

And listening:

```
$ netstat --unix -l
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43115    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     2674     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4772     /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43450    /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4792     @/tmp/fam-root-
```

And my `nginx.conf` includes `upstream_phpcgi_unix.conf` so it should be trying to connect to `php5-fpm` via Unix sockets:

```
## Add as many servers as needed. Cf. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule.
upstream phpcgi {
    ## If your version of Nginx doesn't have the fair load balancer:
    ## https://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair comment out the
    ## following line.
    fair;
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm-zwei.sock;
    ## Create a backend connection cache. Note that this requires
    ## Nginx version greater or equal to 1.1.4.
    ## Cf. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES. Comment out the following
    ## line if that's not the case.
    keepalive 5;
}

## Add a third pool as a fallback.
upstream phpcgi_backup {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm-bkp.sock;
    ## Create a backend connection cache. Note that this requires
    ## Nginx version greater or equal to 1.1.4.
    ## Cf. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES. Comment out the
    ## following line if that's not the case.
    keepalive 1;
}
```

What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using `aptitude purge` to remove all of the PHP packages and their configuration files along with `nginx`. I then reinstalled each PHP package individually as it became necessary. I also used [perusio's PHP-FPM](https://github.com/perusio/php-fpm-example-config) configuration files.